# I have a for loop that asigns characters to char array, error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm making a program, that has a few simple games like Tik Tak Toe, and so on. I made a char array, that contained "x" as cross and "o" as circle. I made a for loop just to assign placeholder characters. When I run it, it underscores the curly bracket at the end of the loop and says "System.IndexOutOfRangeException". What confuses me is how can a for loop be out of bounds.

I tried changing the "i<3" to "i<2".
And even if that worked, I would ask anyways, because I wouldn't understand why it worked

```
char[,] CoC = new char[2, 2];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
     CoC[i, 0] = 'a';
     CoC[i, 1] = 'b';
     CoC[i, 2] = 'c';
}
```

"CoC" stands for CrossOrCircle, "a, b, c" are just placeholders

Comment: How was `CoC` created?  There's not enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: what is the definition of CoC?

Comment: You don't show the code, but the problem is almost the certainly at the point where you declare the array rather than the loop itself.

Comment: @BenVoigt Here.

Comment: @Frenchy Thanks a lot, it works. But how does that make it work?

Comment: @Frenchy Oh, I get it it doesn't represent the max index but the number of elements. Thanks again.

Comment: yes you have understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char[,] CoC = new char[3, 3];
```

will be better because you need an array of [3,3] and not an array [2,2],
your loop indicates 3x3 items

Answer (score 1):

`CoC` is created as `new char[2, 2]`, meaning it has only two elements in each dimension. You'll need to initialize it to a larger size to accommodate the loop you have there:

```
char[,] CoC = new char[3, 3];
// Here -------^--^
```

Comment: I though it represents that the last index is 2. Thanks

Comment: @VojtěchVach, no it represents the size. An array (dimension) of size N will have indexes 0 to N-1.